# how can I hide a sharepoint field from view without removing it (programmatically)

Tags: powershell

I would like to hide a field in the list, but without removing it from the View list.
I would like to uncheck it so that it will not show up when users view the List's default view. In this case I am using the default view.

I used the delete method, but it removed it completely from the view form.

```
$ListViewFields.Delete($fieldInstance)
```

Please see the image below as an example:

[image]

Comment: What type of object $ListViewFields is? Maybe it or $fieldInstance has got .visible member you can set to false?

Answer (score 0):

The List view field names are different than what you see in the GUI (for ex. they don't contain spaces).

I execute the following script to get my list view:

```
$spWeb = Get-SPWeb http://servernamehere/docs/test/sitename
$spList = $spWeb.List["MyList"]
$spView = $spList.DefaultView
```

To view all of the List view fields names available, execute:

```
$spView.ViewFields
```

You will notice that the field names are much different. For ex.:

- Title -> Title
- Title (linked to item) -> LinkFilename
- Type (icon linked to document) -> DocIcon
- Document Author -> Document_x0020_Author

So to remove your highlighted three items, you would execute the following:

```
$spView.ViewFields.Delete("Title")
$spView.ViewFields.Delete("LinkFilename")
$spView.ViewFields.Delete("DocIcon")
$spView.Update()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a tiny hint:

```
$spView.ViewFields
```

in order to display all fields like:

```
"field 1"
"field 2"
"field 3"
```

Then you can safely run:

```
$spView.ViewFields.Delete("field 1")
$spView.Update()
```